# How Can I exclude some files in visual studio finding?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, glob

I have a project in asp.net web form  and I want to search all files which contains `"~/Products"` with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> but I want to exclude a file which is `Server.Transfer("~/Products")`. I tried regex but it did not work. How Can I do this with regex or something else?

I tried

```
*~/Products*;!*Server.Transfer("~/Products")*;
```

Comment: It looks like you are using some glob, not regex pattern to find specific files, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search all files which contains "~/Products" and exclude a file which is Server.Transfer("~/Products").

You can try this regex:

```
^((?!Server\.Transfer).)*~/Products((?!Server\.Transfer).)*$
```